# Using a typical mobile screen on the Unity Google Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm using the Google Cardborad XR Plugin for Unity 1.23.0 package in Unity 2022.3.9f1 version.

When I build the project and install it on my mobile device and run it, the screen is forcibly separated into two screens.

I want to use it like a regular mobile screen, so when I exit VrMode, mobile gyro and object interactions also don't run.

Is there a way to change the screen to a normal mobile screen while using the XR feature on the Unity Cardboard?

The following scripts were used to run and shut down VrMode.

```
    private IEnumerator StartXR()
    {
        Debug.Log("Initializing XR...");
        yield return XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoader();

        if (XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Initializing XR Failed.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("XR initialized.");

            Debug.Log("Starting XR...");
            XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();
            Debug.Log("XR started.");
        }
    }

    private void StopXR()
    {
        Debug.Log("Stopping XR...");
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StopSubsystems();
        Debug.Log("XR stopped.");

        Debug.Log("Deinitializing XR...");
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
        Debug.Log("XR deinitialized.");

        _mainCamera.ResetAspect();
        _mainCamera.fieldOfView = _defaultFieldOfView;
    }
```